# 2D array for a user input name and address

Tags: c, arrays, loops, 2d, printf

I am working on an assignment for class:

Create a program that allows a user to enter up to 10 addresses of friends. Use a two dimensional array to store the address of friends’. After each address is entered, the user should have the option to enter another address or print out a report that shows each addresses entered thus far.

I have created a code that is coming up without errors, but i am not getting the desired results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  char name[10][10] = {0};
  char address[10][10] = {0};
  int choice;

  printf("\n\nWelcome to the address book!\n\n");
  printf("Please enter a name...\n");
  scanf("%s",name);
  printf("Please enter an address...\n");
  scanf("%s",address);

  printf("Would you like to (1)Enter another address, or (2)Print the address book?\n");
  scanf("%i",&choice);
  switch (choice)
  {
    case 1:
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            printf("Please enter a name...\n");
            scanf("%s",name[i]);
            printf("Please enter an address...\n");
            scanf("%s",address[i]);
            printf("Would you like to (1) Enter another address, or (2)Print the address book?\n");
            scanf("%i",&choice);
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    printf("Please enter a name...\n");
                    scanf("%s",name[i]);
                    printf("Please enter an address...\n");
                    scanf("%s",address[i]);
                    printf("Would you like to (1) Enter another address, or (2)Print the address book?\n");
                    scanf("%i",&choice);
                }
            } else if (choice == 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<10; i ++)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", name[i]);
                    printf("%s\n", address[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i ++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", name[i]);
            printf("%s\n", address[i]);
        }
        break;
}
return (0);
}
```

My trouble is coming from the the output. I am able to fill the array but i am not able to print my desired results. Where am I losing it in the loop?

Comment: also after my first entry if I have a space in the "address" input the program just ends. I don't think I constructed the loop the right way.

Comment: In theory there should be 2 loops - one loop to keep asking if client wants to display addresses or enter one, and the other loop to display addresses. The code here has 4 loops. So you're right, you should rearrange the code to just the two loops.

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex, I did want you said a re-read my code. Your correct that having only 2 loops fixed most of my issues. No how to I format the array to hold an entire string. it seems to add to the next name/address if i add a space.

Comment: @Pabeyta Do you know how to use all loops(for() , while(), do while()) perfectly???

Comment: @MudassirHussain as I said I am new to c. I am trying to get as much practice as I can. SO I guess the answer to your question is no. Why do you ask? should i be using somthing different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Program is seems some messy,But As your new to C it is part of learning process.

**Problems:-**

1) For the first time when your program starts, you are asking user for name and address and storing these into arrays,Ok thats fine.But when you are asking same thing again( *what do you want to do...(1)(2)*  ),You are using same array from `i=0` index,This would overwrite the name and address which you have entered during the start of program.And you have done the same thing for every loop.Which would always overwrite the contents of array.

2) Actually your program is called MENU DRIVEN program,Where a menu will always guide user what he wants to do,So You should think like this,"***There should be only one Menu to guide user and should try to reuse this menu***," and **Each Module of Menu should do only one type of thing.**

In you case:-

Choice (1) should ask user to input name and address for storing

Choice (2) should ask user to print the address book.

(But in your program you wrote same code of choice 2 in choice 1,if you want to do the choice 2 in choice 1 why write choice 2 at the first place...???..what i mean is that if you want to execute choice 2 than you have to display the Same Menu back to user.)

After executing a choice, If you want to re-execute it again,you have to keep that choice in
a loop. *(As i did for (1) Choice in below example.because i want to ask user again if he wants enter another name and addresse)*.

```
int main ()
{
  char name[10][10] = {0};
  char address[10][10] = {0};
  int choice;
  int i=0;
  char another; //Variable used to store a another choice...

  while(1) //This is infinite loop....
  {
      printf("Would you like to \n(1) Enter Name and address.\n(2) Print the address book? \n(3) Exit\n");
      scanf("%i",&choice);
      switch (choice) //start of switch.....
      {
          case 1: //start of case 1...
          if(i<10) //executes the below code only if i<10 (if array still has empty cells.)
          {
            do
            {
              printf("Please enter a name...\n");
              scanf("%s",name[i]);
              printf("Please enter an address...\n");
              scanf("%s",address[i]);
              printf("\nWant 2 Enter Another name and address...[y/n]:");
              scanf(" %c",&another);
              i++;
            }while((another=='y'||another=='Y'));
          }

         break; //end of case 1...

         case 2: //start of case 2...
            for ( i = 0; i<10; i ++)
            {
                printf("Name: %s\n", name[i]);
                printf("Address: %s\n\n", address[i]);
            }
         break; //End of case 2...

         case 3:
             return 0;  //This ends program when users enter choice 3..

      } //End of switch...
  }//End of while loop..

}//End of Main Function....
```

Comment: I see! so was the issue that i am writing over my loop? I like that you added an user defined exit. That could prove to be useful in this situation. The problem I am currently having is that my scanf will not read a space it reads "Paul Blart" as two separate entries. other suggestions i am getting is to use fgets. Is this the best way? and why am I having this issue?

Comment: Good Doubt, I see you are Going in right path, Yes your problem was that you were writing over your loop, I should correctly say that you were trying to do same thing in CASE 1 which could be done in CASE 2.And for your 2nd problem DONT use fgets(),you will be suggested to use it but DONT,because it will also read '\n' character which is generated when you hit ENTER key at the end of inputting the name.Use scanf() like this `scanf(" 9[^\n]",name[i]) \\here 9 is sizeof array-1 (to accomadate '\0') and this will read until it finds '\n'` (this is called **scanset** for more info search for it)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow your code as if someone else wrote it, and try to figure out.  If you see something wrong, fix it.

For example: code starts off by asking if user wants to print address book or add to it.
If user selects adding to address book, there's a loop that executes 10 times. In the loop there are two sections where address is being asked for - that seems complicated, why not ask only once?  (At this point fix what seems wrong).

You also have two places where addresses get printed, simplify that to print only once as well.

And finally, this is not what you want:

```
  char name[10][10] = {0};
  char address[10][10] = {0};
```

Either you want this:

```
  char name[10] = {0};
  char address[10] = {0};
```

Or you want:

```
  char address[10][2] = {0}; /* address[x][0] is name, address[x][1] is address */
```

Or you want array of 10 structures.

Edit:
Learning programming requires a lot of trial and error at first. I found a great way to help to understand what the program is doing, is sprinkling the program with:

```
printf("1 -\n");
...
printf("2 -\n");
...
etc.
```

This way when something goes wrong, you know where to start looking.  And remember that computer will do exactly what you tell it to do, so if it's not giving you what you want, you didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: I guess where I get confused is that I need to give the option to print the array or ad to it after every entry. The other issue i run into is that after my first entry if i chose to print it prints correctly, but if I chose to enter another name and address then print  it just closes out.